# How can I find all references of a variable in bootstrap sass folder using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: variables, visual-studio-code, sass, bootstrap-4, reference

I have opened the **Bootstrap SCSS** folder in **Visual Studio Code** and I'm trying to find all of references of a variable (for example: `$display`) in the whole files in that folder and its sub folders, but when I actually do that it seems like VSC only searches the file that variable has been defined there and it's not showing me all the references. How can I achieve that? Or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Finding All References]
[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the bar left there is the magnify glass search tab. Use that search and it should pull up all the occurrences of that variable in other files also.

Comment: I was so obsessed with using the Find References option that I totally forgot about Search option, silly mistake. Thank you!